# How would I run the "start" command on Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, terminal, rubygems

I'm following [this](http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/) guide on fixing a RubyGems SSL issue. I'm stuck on step 2, where they use the `start` command. Mac doesn't have this, so according to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124790/what-is-the-mac-equivalent-of-windows-start-command) discussion I used `open` instead. This opened up code in Xcode, but the tutorial seemed to imply it would open a file browser to get to the ssl_certs directory. Is `open` not equivalent to `start` and if so what should I use? Or is using open correct and I'm doing something else wrong?

What I typed: `Alexs-MBP:~ alextyshka$ open .rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb`

What Xcode opened:
[image: What Xcode opened]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aforementioned tutorial explicitly states:

> Now, let’s locate that directory. From within the same window, enter the path part up to the file extension...

which would be:

```
open .rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems
```

**Windows vs Mac**. Both `start <folder-path>` and `open <folder-path>` opens the specified folder using Windows Explorer or macOS Finder, respectively. But keep in mind that these commands aren't completely identical otherwise.

Comment: Yes that solved it! However, I now have a new error. When trying to install cocoapods, I get this: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)`. Any idea what that is and how to fix it?

Comment: @ATyshka Maybe… what specific command are you using to install CocoaPods on Windows?

Comment: I'm using macOS not Windows

Comment: In the end I had to update rbenv and delete and reinstall Ruby for it to work

Comment: @ATyshka Ok, glad you fixed it ;-)